# ¿Cómo cambiar la fuente de letra del programa en consola de C#?

Tags: c#

En el siguiente código C#, se compila con éxito en un archivo ejecutable y se ejecuta posteriormente:

```
using System;

namespace fuenteLetra {
    class Programa {
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            //PARÁMETROS
            Console.Title = "Título de la ventana";

            //PROGRAMA
            Console.Write("El programa tiene otra fuente de letra");
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, la consola actual es de Windows 7, por lo que la fuente de letra es fuente de mapa de bits. En Windows 10, la fuente cambia a Consolas y/o Lucida Console.

He investigado pero aparecen funciones muy complejas para cambiar la fuente de letra.

¿Se puede cambiar la fuente de letra de un programa de consola con un simple parámetro o similar?

Supongo que puede ser algo como `Console.Font = "Consolas"`, pero no funciona.

Comment: Para solucionar este problema también puedes hacer lo siguiente: **1)** Presionas las **teclas Windows + R**. **2)** En la ventana que te sale escribes **cmd** y aprietas la **tecla Enter**. **3)** Cuando te salga la **Consola de Windows**, párate en la **barra de título** de dicha ventana, da clic derecho y escoges la **opción Predeterminados** y escoges la fuente que deseas. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2TeH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2TeH.png) **Nota:** Quizás ya esto lo sabias, pero igual respondo porque podría ser útil para otros.

Comment: No entiendo qué más debe hacer el OP para que la pregunta no esté fuera de tema; la pregunta tiene +3...

Comment: @Alfabravo que la pregunta sea bien recibida o tenga votos positivos ... no quiere decir que sea aceptable en el sitio ... incluso responder a preguntas off topic puede ser motivo de que las respuesta reciban votos negativo incluso aunque responda la pregunta y estén correctamente planteadas . solo acalrandote este punto ... pero la pregunta parece estar correctamente planteada yo vote cierre por que hacían falta detalles ... pero otras dos personas votaron por offt-opic...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent todo eso lo tengo claro. Mi pregunta sobre la pregunta es abierta (a todos los que votaron) y por eso voté para reabrir esto. El OP busca una aproxiación programática a un problema concreto de programación. Si faltan detalles, porfa pídanlos acá en los comentarios.

Answer (score -1):

Como has podido ver, no es trivial porque estás yendo a modificar el comportamiento de una aplicación externa, que además no es muy versátil y tiende a estar medio acoplada al OS.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62763047/236345) comentan una opción, donde creas un Helper con algunos métodos que te ayuden a hacer esa tarea y luego lo invocas en tu programa usando el método `SetCurrentFont` que implementa el Helper.

Proponen un helper (`ConsoleHelper.cs`) maomenos así:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class ConsoleHelper
{
    private const int FixedWidthTrueType = 54;
    private const int StandardOutputHandle = -11;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, bool MaximumWindow, ref FontInfo ConsoleCurrentFontEx);

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern bool GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(IntPtr hConsoleOutput, bool MaximumWindow, ref FontInfo ConsoleCurrentFontEx);


    private static readonly IntPtr ConsoleOutputHandle = GetStdHandle(StandardOutputHandle);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct FontInfo
    {
        internal int cbSize;
        internal int FontIndex;
        internal short FontWidth;
        public short FontSize;
        public int FontFamily;
        public int FontWeight;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.wc, SizeConst = 32)]
        public string FontName;
    }

    public static FontInfo[] SetCurrentFont(string font, short fontSize = 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Set Current Font: " + font);

        FontInfo before = new FontInfo
        {
            cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FontInfo>()
        };

        if (GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutputHandle, false, ref before))
        {

            FontInfo set = new FontInfo
            {
                cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FontInfo>(),
                FontIndex = 0,
                FontFamily = FixedWidthTrueType,
                FontName = font,
                FontWeight = 400,
                FontSize = fontSize > 0 ? fontSize : before.FontSize
            };

            // Get some settings from current font.
            if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutputHandle, false, ref set))
            {
                var ex = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Console.WriteLine("Set error " + ex);
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ex);
            }

            FontInfo after = new FontInfo
            {
                cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<FontInfo>()
            };
            GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutputHandle, false, ref after);

            return new[] { before, set, after };
        }
        else
        {
            var er = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine("Get error " + er);
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(er);
        }
    }
}
```

Fíjate en cómo carga los dll al comienzo para poder interactuar con la configuración de la consola.

Para usar el helper, en tu código harías algo como

```
ConsoleHelper.SetCurrentFont("Consolas", 10);
```

O puedes ir por la opción no programática, ir a la configuración del perfil de la Consola para tu sesión de Windows, cambiar la fuente y ya está :)

Comment: será que lo quiere hacer de manera programática?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ni idea! En vez de poner un comentario en cada respuesta, pregúntale al OP comentando la pregunta. Por eso hay votos de cierre: algunos opinarán que debe cerrarse, otros no y está bien que asi sea.

Comment: es que ya eso esta en la pregunta ... **el siguiente código C#, se compila con éxito en un archivo ejecutable y se ejecuta**

Comment: Entonces vota negativamente la respuesta  si crees que no es una buena respuesta. :) PD. El enlace es a otra pregunta donde programáticamente hacen el cambio

Comment: y si no sabe ingles el usuario????

Comment: Me gustó ese comentario tanto que lo voté +1 y edité la pregunta. Gracias por el llamado al orden :)